# Is it possible to monitor host instance and java app on that instance using two prometheus exporters

Tags: prometheus

I have my java app deployed using Docker.
I want to collect host metrics (cpu/ram/storage etc) as well as JMX metrics (heap stats, threads etc).
Also it would be nice to use auto-discovery feature (my app deployed into EC2 instance).

The only way I see to do this is to setup exporters on the different ports an setup prometheus to consume both exporters, but not sure how this will work with auto-discovery.

Will it be possible to aggregate metrics of host and app then?

Answer (score 0):

It will works exactly as it works separately. The specific ports by exporter is done exactly for these case.

Each metrics will be stored inside the prometheus database, each as it's own entry.